# Can I manually extract email files from backups created by Plesk?

Tags: email, backup, plesk

I have made a email backup with plesk for a particular domain. Now i like to extract/import the emails in email program local. 
When i unzip domain.com_mn_1112091008.tgz i get a .discorvery folder and another .zip file.

How can i import the emails with their corresponding attachments?

Regards

Comment: What version of plesk ? what method of backup did you use ?

Comment: Hi i use plesk 9.5 and i made a backup with the built-in backup manager>> Domain configuration and content>>Only mail configuration and content.

Answer (score 0):

NO can one can extract .tgz file in plesk panel.
I can only done via on your desktop with WinRar Software or you can upload .tgz file thorugh backup manager and then click on uploaded and then click on Restore.